# AJax GETs correct value, Returns an include file?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I am absolutely baffled here.

I have a form in html that allos a user to compile a list of Doc IDs.  Upon clicking my create button, I am alerted with the values of these Doc IDs and need them to be sent to my ASP page to format the string as needed to then return the formated string and populate a textarea with it.  I have completely removed my ASP page from the equation here because somehow this obscure problem is occuring on my primary page.

When I click my create button, the alert box pops up with the correct value but then instead of throwing it into my textarea it populates the text area with an include file from the page, full CSS and everything.  I have never seen anything like it.  In Firebug I get no information as to why this is the response text or anything.

What's stranger, is I have set this up in jsFiddle and here, I have the exact same code but this time, I get the correct result:
http://jsfiddle.net/VNUUV/

This has me at my wit's end and I need some insight.  The code on my actual testing page is identical to what's on JS Fiddle there.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I click the button I see `111111,222222,333333,444444` in an alert and the textarea... is that what you're expecting?

Comment: Yes.  But when I run the page in my actual environment with the URL parameter in the Ajax part of the function, it returns an include file.  It gets the correct values but once sent to ASP it returns a bunch of garbage for some reason.

Comment: Can you post exactly what that garbage is. My guess would be that it's an IIS error message of some description.

Comment: It's literally an include file.  It's comprised of CSS and Javascript calls.  So technically not garbage but definitely not my expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible a scenario where what you are experiencing might occur.  An IIS server that does not have ASP feature installed might treat asp files as standard content files.  Server side includes would still work.

Your firm page is just html so renders fine. However your Ajax request just brings back the script text of the asp page after the includes have resolved.